# Find probability $P(X|A,B)$ given conditionals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

Let $A,B,X$ be discrete random variables taking values on finite spaces, and where $A$ and $B$ are statistically independent.

By the law of total probability one has
$$P(x_i|A=a)=\sum_b P(x_i | A=a, B=b)P(B=b|A=a)=\sum_b P(x_i | A=a, B=b)P(B=b)$$
At the same time, interchanging the papers of $A$ and $B$
$$P(x_i|B=b)=\sum_a P(x_i | A=a, B=b)P(A=a)$$
Furthermore, suppose that $P(A=a)=1/|A|$ for all $a\in A$ and $P(B=b)=1/|B|$ for all $b\in B$.
I thought one should expect to have
$$\sum_{a,b} P(x_i | A=a, B=b)=|A|\sum_b P(x_i|B=b)=|B|\sum_a P(x_i|A=a)$$
However with certain given conditional probabilities $P(x|A)$ and $P(x|B)$ I am getting $$|A|\sum_b P(x_i|B=b) \neq |B|\sum_a P(x_i|A=a)$$
Why is this happening, and is there any way by which one can calculate $P(x|A,B)$ given only $P(x|A)$,$P(x|B)$, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

Comment: Does the distinction between uppercase $P$ and lowercase $p$ denote anything, or are these just lots of typos?

Comment: Yes, ignore that. I am editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations
$$P(x_i|B=b)=\sum_a P(x_i | A=a, B=b)P(A=a),\quad P(x_i|A=a)=\sum_b P(x_i | A=a, B=b)P(B=b)$$
together with $P(A=a)=1/|A|$, and $P(B=b)=1/|B|$, certainly imply
$$\sum_{a,b} P(x_i | A=a, B=b)=|A|\sum_b P(x_i|B=b)=|B|\sum_a P(x_i|A=a)\tag1$$
Therefore, you have made some mistake with your supposed counterexample to $(1)$. I cannot say more without you saying what your counterexample was.

---

In general, you cannot compute $P(X|A,B)$ given only $P(X|A),P(X|B),P(A)$ and $P(B)$. Consider this situation. Suppose $P(A)=P(B)=1/2$, and that 
\begin{array}{r|cc}
& B & \overline B\\
\hline
A & p+\epsilon & p-\epsilon\\
\overline A & p-\epsilon & p+\epsilon\\
\end{array}
Each entry in the table gives the conditional probability of $X$ the events in the row and column header. For example, $P(X|A,\overline B)=p-\epsilon$. Note that $P(X|A)=P(X|\overline A)=P(X|B)=P(X|\overline B)=p$, so these conditional probabilities give no information about $\epsilon$, so you cannot compute $P(X|A,B)$ using them alone.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/9j6Y8ca for a counterexample to (1). Here A has 4 elements and B 2 elements.

Comment: There is no probability space with those probabilities. Imaging using the left table to compute P(salmon), by conditioning on the season: you would get (0.9 + 0.3 + 0.4 + 0.8)/4. If you instead used the second table you would get P(salmon) = (0.65 + 0.25)/2. These are unequal, which is a contradiction. You cannot arbitrarily assign conditional probabilities $P(x_i|a_j)$ and $P(x_i|b_j)$ and expect them to make sense. @user57284

Comment: Okay, I get it. The example is not mine, I took it from the book Pattern Classification by Richard O.Duda et al. in the context of Bayesian Belief Networks. They 'somehow' end up calculating $\sum_{i,j} P(x_1|a_i,b_j)$. without more info than what I stated here. So either the book is wrong or I am missing something.